# Segregating portions of a matrix into variables - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
numSeg = 10;        %Set number of segments
wSeg = 10;      %Set segment width
x = ones(1,numSeg*wSeg);
```

What would be the most efficient way to automatically provide a variable for each created segment? For example:

```
bin1 = x(1:10)
bin2 = x(11:20)
```

and so on.

Eventually I will generate a number at random (1:numSeg) to pick a bin and then alter it:

[image]

I am primarily stuck on how to be able to refer a specific region of a matrix using a variable name or a number (such as bin number) such that I can make the alteration - which would be nothing more than multiplying the chosen region within 'x' by another matrix that is wSeg wide. I'd rather not have to manually specify each bin1, bin2, bin3 etc.

Comment: I need x to be 1:numSeg*wSeg but populated with 1's.

Comment: The image shows `x = 1:100`, which means `x = [1,2,3,4...100]`, whereas the code reads `x = ones(1,100)`, i.e. `x=[1,1,1,...1(100 times)]`. So, this might confuse others. I would still think that `x` must be `1:100 i.e. [1,2,..100]` rather than all ones, because in the latter case you don't need to index into `x` anyway as any indexing into all ones array would yield just ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for segment_id = 1:numSeg
    bin = x((segment_id-1)*wSeg+1 : segment_id*wSeg) %// x values for each segment. 
         %// So, for segment_id = 1, you would have bin as x(1:10)
         %//     for segment_id = 2, you would have bin as x(11:20)
         %// ........
         %//     for segment_id = 10, you would have bin as x(91:100) 
end
```

So, you can get a random segment_id with `segment_id = randi([1 numSeg])` and then use -

```
bin = x((segment_id-1)*wSeg+1 : segment_id*wSeg)
```

to get the bin values of that particular random segment.

As an example, I typed in -

```
segment_id = randi([1 numSeg])
```

I got -

```
segment_id =
     7
```

Then, I use `bin = x((segment_id-1)*wSeg+1 : segment_id*wSeg)` that gave me -

```
ans =
    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70
```

Comment: I am not sure if this addresses my issue. My apologies as I may have made my original post unclear - i've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're looking for is how to store the indices of each bin in a format that is convenient to access/use. There are of course a lot of ways to do it. Here's one that I personally think works well, but your mileage may vary.

What you already have:

```
numSeg = 10;        %//Set number of segments
wSeg = 10;      %//Set segment width
x = ones(1,numSeg*wSeg);
```

Create the indices and store them in a cell array:

```
linear_indices = 1:numSeg*wSeg; %// row vector
bin = mat2cell(linear_indices,1,ones(1,numSeg)*wSeg); %// cell array gives flexibility in bin size, if you need it
```

Use the index to access bin 4:

```
x(bin{4});
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you. The final line defining `bin` currently returns the error: `Error using mat2cell (line 107)
Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [1  100].'` but I am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann It is fixed now - I'd forgotten the requirements for the arguments to mat2cell - give it a try. As you move forward with the project it may be beneficial to be able to keep arbitrary sets of indices as bins, instead of hard-coding the rule into your actual indexing step. At the very least it should be easier to document and maintain this way.